# Handle WIF SignInResponseMessage (Post) when user requests action method with both [HttpGet] & [HttpPost] overloads]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, federated-identity, wif

I thought the solution to this would occur to me as I've sat on this problem for many months - but my brain has not flags the obvious best approach.

I have two controller methods say "Edit" that are protected with an action filter that causes passive authentication to an STS.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id) { [do stuff] }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id, EditViewModel model) { [do stuff] }
```

The problem is, mvc receives the SignInResponseMessage and then fires the HttpPost which is not what I want... Anyone out there approached this issue and feel they've got a nice solution?

I guess I could uniquely name all my action methods if worst comes to worse i.e. the good old mvc1 Edit() vs Update() / New() vs Create() etc..

Comment: Have you tryed to call the Controller with an ActionLink to see if it was called via GET? Do you see a POST in this case?

Comment: The use case is from just pasting a url into the browser and hitting enter (causing a get, which redirects to the STS). From what I understand the way the token / WIF session is create is via a post...

Comment: I have found this article, may be that can help.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347547.aspx
In the Figure 2 you can se that the browser send a POST after call the STS, but I don't know if it's your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution...

Instead of allowing the STS to post to any url (and hit any action in the application), I use a setting in my STS to post to one url which has an action method that looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index() {

    if (MyIdentity.IsAuthenticated) {
        if (ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request["wreply"] != null)
        {
            var returnUrl = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request["wreply"];
            if (returnUrl.StartsWith(Stgs.WebRt)) { return Redirect(returnUrl); } //make sure the wreply is actually for this application and not a random url
        }

        return Redirect("/"); 
    }

    return View(); 
}
```

Then in the STS when I'm building the SignOutResponseMessage I add the line:

```
response.SetParameter("wreply", message.Reply);
```

where "reponse" is a Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSFederation.SignInReponseMessage and "message" is a is a Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSFederation.SignInRequestMessage. This basically adds the wreply as a form input that is posted to the relying party. Hence making the controller action code above work as expected.